# How to limit total size of files that a user can upload to Firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have an application that should allow users to upload files totaling 150 GB per user and should prevent users from uploading new files beyond that. How can I add this restriction?

Comment: You may have to use Cloud functions or a server as a middleman to validate this.

Comment: May you please explain how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to upload the files through a Cloud function/server and keep track of total size that a user has uploaded:

```
1. Upload image to your server
2. check the size and add it to total size stored in a database
3. If the user has exceeded 150 GB, return quota exceeded error else upload to Firebase storage

user -> server -> Firebase storage
```

An easier alternative would be to use [Cloud Storage Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) which will trigger a Cloud function every time a new file is uploaded. You can check the object size using the [metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_storage_.objectmetadata#size) and keep adding it in database. In this case, you can store total storage used by a user in [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) in bytes.

```js
exports.updateTotalUsage = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
  // check total storage currently used
  // add size of new object to it
  // update custom claim "size" (total storage in bytes)
});
```

Then you can write a security rule that checks sum of size of new object and total storage being used does not exceed 150 GB:

```
allow write: if request.resource.size + request.auth.token.size < 150 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

Comment: I really feel gratitude towards you for answering this question. Thank you. You solved my problem.