# How can I set limit on the amount of storage that each user can upload to Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-storage, firebase-security

I am struggling to find out how to set the limit of the storage that each user can upload to my apps storage.

I found method online `Storage.storageLimitInBytes` method, but I don't see this method even be mentioned in Firebase docs, let alone instructions on how to set it.

In general, how do startups monitor how many times user upload images, would they have a field in users document such as `amountOfImagesUploaded:` and everytime user uploads image I would increment that count and this way I could see who abuse the storage that way.

Or would I have to similar document that tracks users uploads per day and when the count reaches 100 or something then take action on that user.

I would really appreciate your help regarding this issue that I am facing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate Firebase storage consumption per user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68927291/how-to-calculate-firebase-storage-consumption-per-user)

Answer (score 5):

Limits in Cloud Storage for Firebase security rules apply to each file/object separately, they don't apply to an entire operation.
You can limit what a user can upload through [Firebase Storage's security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/). For example, [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/#data_validation) (from the linked docs) is a way to limit the size of uploaded files:

```
service firebase.storage { 
match /b/<your-firebase-storage-bucket>/o { 
match /images/{imageId} { // Only allow uploads of any image file that's less than 5MB 
allow write: if request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024 && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*'); 
} } }
```

But there is currently no way in these rules to limit the number of files a user can upload.
Some options to consider:

1. If you hardcode the names of the files that the user uploads (which
   also implies you'll limit the number of files they can upload), and
   create a folder for the files for each specific user, you can
   determine the sum of all files in a user's folder, and thus limit on
   the sum in that way.

   For example :  If you fix file names and limit the allowed file
   names to be numbered 1..5, the user can only ever have five files in
   storage:

   ```
   match /public/{userId}/{imageId} { 
   allow write: if imageId.matches("[1-5]\.txt"); 
   }
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can ZIP all files together on the client, and
   then upload the resulting archive. In that case, the security rules
   can enforce the maximum size of that file.
3. And of course you can include client-side JavaScript code to check
   the maximum size of the combined files in both of these cases. A
   malicious user can bypass this JavaScript easily, but most users
   aren't malicious and will thank you for saving their bandwidth by
   preventing the upload that will be rejected anyway.
4. You can also use a HTTPS Cloud Function as your upload target, and
   then only pass the files onto Cloud Storage if they meet your
   requirements. Alternatively you can use a Cloud Function that
   triggers upon the upload from the user, and validates the files for
   that user after the change.      For example : You would have to
   upload the files through a Cloud function/server and keep track of
   the total size that a user has uploaded. For that,

   - Upload image to your server
   - Check the size and add it to total size stored in a database
   - If the user has exceeded 150 GB, return quota exceeded error else    upload to Firebase storage user -> server -> Firebase storage
5. An easier alternative would be to use [Cloud Storage Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) which
   will trigger a Cloud function every time a new file is uploaded. You
   can check the object size using the metadata and keep adding it in
   the database. In this case, you can store total storage used by a
   user in [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) in bytes.

   ```
   exports.updateTotalUsage = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => { 
   // check total storage currently used 
   // add size of new object to it 
   // update custom claim "size" (total storage in bytes) 
   })
   ```

   Then you can write a security rule that checks sum of size of new
   object and total storage being used does not exceed 150 GB:  allow
   write: if request.resource.size + request.auth.token.size < 150 *
   1024 * 1024
6. You can also have a look at this thread too if you need a per user
   storage validation. The solution is a little bit tricky, but can be
   done with :
   https://medium.com/@felipepastoree/per-user-storage-limit-validation-with-firebase-19ab3341492d

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud (or Firebase environment) doesn't know the users. It knows your application and your application do.

if you want to have statistic per users you have to logs those data somewhere and perform sum/aggregations to have your metrics.

A usual way is to use Firestore to store those information and to increment the number of file or the total space used.

An unusual solution is to log each action in Cloud Logging and to perform a sink from Cloud Logging to BigQuery to find your metrics in BigQuery and perform aggregation directly from there (the latency is higher, all depends on what you want to achieve, sync or async check of those metrics)