# How to limit file size 5mb in firebase storage?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I want to add a security rule to prevent spamming with huge amount of data. It does matter where the path is, the rule is the max file is 5mb. I tried:

```
rules_version = '2';

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null &&  request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    }
  }
}
```

But it does not work:

> flutter: [firebase_storage/unauthorized] User is not authorized to perform the desired action.

@Doug

Yes there are two constraints in rule: 1)  User must be authenticated and 2) File must not exceed the limit

It works with `request.auth != null`  only (which used to be before I added the limit.)  Because the user is authenticated when making the call.

@Ruchit

It does not work with `request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024` only,
I tried that already

@Doug here is the client code.

```
class FirebaseStorageService {
  Future<String?> uploadImageToFirebase(Uint8List imageFile) async {
    try {
      print("uploading image to firebase storage... size: ${imageFile.length}");
      final storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
      final Reference storageReference =
          storage.ref().child('images/${DateTime.now()}.jpg');
      final UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putData(
          imageFile,
          SettableMetadata(
            contentType: 'image/jpg',
          ));
      final TaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot = await uploadTask;
      final String downloadUrl = await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      return downloadUrl;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set limit on the amount of storage that each user can upload to Firebase Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70969541/how-can-i-set-limit-on-the-amount-of-storage-that-each-user-can-upload-to-fireba)

Comment: can you remove request.auth != null and then try the size part only?

Comment: You rule has two constraints: 1) the user must be authenticated, 2) the size of the file must be within a limit.  We can't tell which constraint might be causing the rejection.  Please edit the question to show the client code that doesn't work the way you expect, showing clearly that both constraints are being met by that code. There should be enough information that anyone can reproduce the issue using your instructions.

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated the questions with the relevant informations

Comment: @Ruchit I updated the question with the relevant information